# rtmp nodejs server config on NGINX _ nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: node.js, nginx, rtmp

I have [media server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server) running on port 1935 .

and I have a subdomain: **"streaming.foo.com"**

I need to configure Nginx to access **rtmp://streaming.foo.com**

I tried the RTMP Nginx plugin  with this blog :

https://www.nginx.com/blog/video-streaming-for-remote-learning-with-nginx/

and configured the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        application live {
            live on;
            dash on;
            dash_path /tmp/dash; // what is this config??
            dash_fragment 15s;
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error from nginx :

> nginx[176987]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98:
> Address already in use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `RTMP`, not `HTTP`. Nginx is a web server, which can proxy and balance `HTTP` only. It is not a general proxy server.

Use a general Proxy or Load balancer, like `HA Proxy`.

Comment: Nginx has a module for RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two services listening on the same port.

The common solution is to configure the real service (your media service) on another port (let's say 19350) than configure a reverse proxy on nginix to forward requests from the exposed port (1935 in this case) to the back-end service (19350 in our example).

Sorry but I don't know nginix (I use this config with apache) so I can't help you on how to configure a reverse proxy on it.

Comment: tnx for the reply , I need to know can I use my subdomain for addressing RTMP server directly without any reverse proxies?

Comment: any news on this?